# Implementing poll() using select() system call

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, select

```
static int send_dg(...)
{
    ...
      const u_char buf;
      int buflen;
      struct pollFd pfd[1];

      /* Create NON-Blocking UDP socket */
      pfd[0].fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);

      /* Connect to the server */
      connect(pfd[0].fd, serverAddress, serverLength);

      /* Make socket as NON-BLOCKING */
      int flag = __fcntl(pfd[0].fd, F_GETFL);
      __fcntl(pfd[0].fd, F_SETFL, flag|O_NONBLOCK);

      pfd[0].events = POLLOUT;

      /* GLIBC: Below poll() system call returns 1 */
      /* Unlike uClibc, ZERO timeout poll returns 
      immediately even if there is NO event on FD */
      poll(pfd, 1, 0);

      /* Send the UDP datagram to the server */
      send(pfd[0].fd, buf, buflen, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    ...
}
```

In the above logic, I should implement my own poll() using select() system call. Can I replace `poll(fd, 1, 0);` with below piece of code? Will select return 1?

```
int sock_id = pfd[0].fd;
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
select(sock_id+1, (fd_set *)NULL, (fd_set *)NULL, (fd_set *)NULL, &timeout);
```

Comment: I think you need to [read more about `select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

Comment: I understand that select() monitors multiple file descriptors (read/write/exception) and waits until at least one file descriptor (in the fd_set) is ready for some I/O operation (read/write). 
If the timeout value is ZERO, select() returns immediately. I wonder whether it SHOULD return 0 or 1.
If I don't want to monitor any file-descriptor (mentioning NULL for all 3 types of FD), what is the behavior of select()?

Comment: Your use of `poll` is not equal to your use of `select`. With your `poll` call you check if a single descriptor can be written to, you don't do that check with `select` (since the "write" `fd_set` is a null pointer).

Comment: I tried monitoring my write-file-descriptor using `select()` with zero timeout.
`int sock_id = pfd[0].fd;
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
select(sock_id+1, (fd_set *)NULL, &pollFd, (fd_set *)NULL, &timeout);`

The `select` call TIMEDOUT immediately and returned 0. Once the socket is connected successfully, monitoring the FD for an activity is NOT possible with ZERO timeout?

Comment: And *thats* why you should read the manual page, and learn about the `FD_*` macros and the `fd_set`  type and how it is used. You can't use the same structures as you use for `poll`.